# Calculate how thick the continent is

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, estimation, geophysics

I have a task that I'm stuck on:

For simplicity's sake, we assume that a continent consists of an even thick surface of granite that floats in peridotite. If a continent protrudes 5.0 km above the material in which the continent flows, how thick is the continent? In granite, the density is 2800 kg/m3 and in periodotite it is 3300 kg/m3.

How can i figure out if out if I don't know the volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of the continent as a slab of granite floating on a "sea" of denser peridotite. Suppose the continent is $x$ m thick, of which $5000$ m is above the peridotite and $(x-5000)$ m is submerged. If the continent has area $A$ m^2 then the mass of the continent is

$2800Ax$ kg

and the displaced mass of peridotite is

$3300A(x-5000)$ kg

Archimedes principles tell us that these two masses must be equal, so

$2800Ax = 3300A(x-5000) \\ \Rightarrow 2.8x = 3.3(x-5000)$

(Notice that we don't need to know the value of the area $A$ because it cancels out.)

From this you can find the value of $x$. Remember that $x$ is in metres, so if you want a thickness in km you need to divide by $1000$.

Comment: Thank you. Did not think about that, will help me for future tasks!

Comment: Please check your units. For example, if "the continent is $x$ m thick", then "$x$ is in metres" cannot both be correct at the same time; if "$x-5000\ \mathrm m$ is submerged" then you cannot calculate "$(x-5000)$". Also note that proper quantity equations are preferred to numerical value equations because quantity equations are independent of the choice of measurement units.

Comment: @Loong I believe my units are correct and consistent. I am working in metres and kg because the density values given are in kg per cubic metre. We know $5$km of the continental plate is above the surface of the peridotite so if the total thickness of the continental plate is $x$ metres then the submerged depth is $x-5000$ metres - what is wrong with that ?

Comment: Your last sentence "if the total thickness of the continental plate is $x$ metres then the submerged depth is $x−5000\ \mathrm m$" describes the problem with your way of using the units. In the expression "$x$ metres", $x$ itself is dimensionless; in the expression $x−5000\ \mathrm m$, however, $x$ is in metres. You can avoid such problems when using quantity equations; i.e. use "the thickness of the plate is $x$" rather than "the thicknes of the plate is $x$ metres".

Comment: @Loong Ok, I see where your confusion is. $x$ is in metres, $5000$ is in metres and $x-5000$ is also in metres. I guess to be toally clear I should have written $(x-5000)$ metres but I thought brackets would be understood. Anyway, I have updated my answer.